# error when use Moment.js not accept to save in DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

when I try to use `Moment.js` in server code and do save action I get this error
are there any solution or any alternative to change `Date` format

```
{
      stringValue: '"March 15th 2022, 2:28:00 am"',
      messageFormat: undefined,
      kind: 'date',
      value: 'March 15th 2022, 2:28:00 am',
      path: 'transactionTime',
      reason: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:
        assert.ok(false)
        generatedMessage: true,
        code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
        actual: false,
        expected: true,
        operator: '=='
      },
      valueType: 'string'
    }
  },
  _message: 'transaction validation failed'
}
```

Schema

```
var moment = require('moment');

const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    transactionTime: {
        type: Date,
        default: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'),
    },
    ...
})
```

Comment: Share some code please?

Comment: I do it you can check the post again.

Comment: **Never** store date values as string! Use `default: moment().toDate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must let the type save in DB as `Date` and in `default: Date.now()` or if I use moment in Server code `default: () => moment().toDate()` then change the format after getting the value from DB
like this

```
moment(transaction.transactionTime).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
```